# Netsuite schedule a saved search and HTTP POST?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm new to Suitescript and Netsuite automation in general. What I want to do is very basic. I want to schedule a saved search to execute every few hours and then post the resultant XML to an HTTP target. I have a bundle that does this for a connector but it doesn't let me see the contents so it's a bit of a black box. Does anyone have an example script I might adapt? I'd appreciate any configuration notes you might have as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a very basic idea.  I don't use XML, though, so this example is using JSON.  This also assumes that you have a saved search you want to get the results from, and that there is only one row of data.  If you have multiple rows, you would just declare a new array of data before the run().each() block, and push each new role of data into it at the end of that block.

```
define(['N/search','N/https'],function(search,https){
  function execute(context){
    search.load({
      id:1234 // This should be your Saved Search ID
    }).run().each(function(result){
      var columns=result.columns;
      var column0=result.getValue(columns[0]);
      var column1=result.getValue(columns[0]);
      var column2=result.getValue(columns[0]);
      var column3=result.getValue(columns[0]);

      return true;
    });

    var postData={
        "column0":column0,
        "column1":column1,
        "column2":column2,
        "column3":column3,
    };
    postData=JSON.stringify(postData);
    var header=[];
    header['Content-Type']='application/json';
    header['Accept']='application/json';
    var apiURL='https://whereverYouAreSendingThis.com';
    try{
      var response=https.post({
        url:apiURL,
        headers:header,
        body:postData
      });
      var response=response.body;
    }catch(er01){
      log.error('ERROR',JSON.stringify(er01));
    }
    return true;
  }
  return {
    execute: execute
  };
});
```

That should get you started on the basic functionality of what you are trying to do.